# Why isn't horniness in the list of Ekman's six basic emotions?

Tags: emotion

Does the basic emotion research consider horniness an emotion, does it consider it to be an aspect of one of the other six basic emotions?
Did Ekman and other researchers ignore it because it's harder to study in the contexts where they did their research?

Comment: Why ask about horniness specifically? Why not hunger? Thirst? What makes you think it should be an *emotion*? (ideally, support this with references)

Comment: @BryanKrause : There's no facial expression I would associate with hunger and thirst the way I would associate one with horniness. Facial expressions seem to be pretty core to Ekman's research.